# Which Has Better Performance - Configuration In AppSettings or Database?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, configuration

I'm looking for feedback as to where I should store application configuration data and default text values that will have the best performance overall.  For example, I've been sticking stuff like default URL values and the default text for error messages or application instructions inside the web.config, but now I'm wondering if that will scale....and if it's even the right thing to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a single server setup (as opposed to a Web farm) store it in the Web.Config file. There is a new release of the Web Farm framework and you could check details for that type of scenario here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/08/introducing-the-microsoft-web-farm-framework.aspx

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before, this really shouldn't matter - the settings, be they in the web.config or in a database, should be 'read-once' and then cached, so this really shouldn't matter.

I can almost guarantee that there will be other parts of your code much slower than this.

---

As a side note, and not performance related, but if you need to worry about site uptime, you can edit configuration in a database on the fly, but changing the web.config will cause an appdomain restart and subsequent loss of sessions.

Comment: Well, just to be clear...I'm not "worried" about this as much as I was just looking for feedback as to how others store their config data.  What the difference in performance would be during the initial load, as well as subsequent loads, does matter to me.  This question is not concerned with the other parts of my code, as it all adds up in the end...right?

Comment: @Cognitronic - apologies if that was a bit confrontational, not meant to be.  The other answers will apply, if this performance is important, particularly the part about distance to your SQL server.

Comment: No sweat...yeah, I know there are lots of other things to worry about and wrestle with.  I was just hoping to get responses regarding the question.  I appreciate you taking the time to post!! :)

Comment: @Cognitronic - I would note that the web.config doesn't seem the right place for strings that you display to the user or instructions.  If you want to keep these in files, you should look at least at splitting them out into separate xml files.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is on the same machine performance difference may be neglect-able. If you need to cross a wire to get to some database it's most likely slower then a directly accessible and not too large web.config.

I really would prefer keeping things simple here, just use the web.config. It probably is already getting cached in memory by some system component. If you feel it's too slow measure it and then perhaps go for a more complicated solution.

Having said that you could simply read in all configuration at application start-up and hold it in memory. This way any performance difference is mitigated to just the application's start-up time. You also get the added benefit of being able to validate the configuration files at start-up.

Not sure about your defaults but just ask yourself if they are environment specific and is it really something you want to change without recompilation. Being configuration files, what is the use case? Is some operations guy or developer going to set these defaults? Are you planning to document them? Are you going to make your application robust against whatever is configured?
Are these defaults going to be used on multiple environments/installations (used for localization for instance)? Then perhaps it's better to use a different and separate file which you can redeploy separately when needed.

Answer (score 0):

How often are the settings going to change?

If they never change, you can probably put them in web.config, and configure IIS so that it doesn't monitor the file for changes.  That will impose a small startup penalty, but after that there should be no performance penalty.

But honestly, there are probably dozens of other places to improve before you start worrying about this - remember, "[Premature Optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)" :)

Comment: Most settings probably will not change too often, but just how often is unknown.  As I said below, I'm not "Worried" about this....I'm just looking for feedback regarding the question.